# .net6 upgrade. MapControllers method fails

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I am upgrading API project from .net5 to .net6

It worked before, now it crashes with

- Inner Exception Message  "Exception of type 'Unity.Exceptions.InvalidRegistrationException' was thrown."
- Message  "No public constructor is available for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorViewEngine."

at

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

I did some investigation and
changing from

```
services.AddControllers();
```

to

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

helps.

This is a pure api project. No views, no mvc, etc. I have a solution, but I am trying to understand the reason. Why should I do this change? I am missing something so I should change some other place.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my runtime to 6.0.5, and the issued was fixed.

Answer (score -2):

This is because [Unity is a dead project and will not be updated going forward](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/discussions/368#discussioncomment-1609377), so any incompatibilities with .NET 6 will not be fixed.

I honestly don't understand why you'd want to use Unity in 2021 anyway, when the dependency injection built into .NET works so well.

Comment: Seems that some legacy stuff that "just worked" starts to bring pain.

Comment: Such is the problem with legacy software, it "just works" until you no longer have an upgrade path... then it doesn't work at all. But that is a choice that you, or your company, makes... and choices have consequences.

Comment: As pointed out in the very same github issue you linked, it is mentioned that the "out of the box" DI does not support everything that's needed out there. See https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/discussions/368#discussioncomment-1721913

Comment: I get an issue with MapControllers() also after upgrade from .NET5 to .NET6, but instead System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: But services.AddControllersWithViews(); did not fix my issue.